# Stop iteration from inside a function

Tags: python, iterator, break

I am using an iterator to flexiblily go through a collection. In my function there are several cases in which the function gets a new item and processes them. So there are several cases in which something like this happens:

```
it = iter(range(10))
while condition:
    try:
        item = next(it)
        item.do_many_different_things()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

And that makes everything extremly messy, so I wanted to move it into a seperate methode. But than I can't use break, because python doesn't know what loop it should break. So far I'm returning a None type, and break the loop if a None was returned. But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Use a `for` loop for iteration. That would be "elegant"

Answer (score 0):

You can **return** value from the `do_many_different_things()` function and change the `condition` variable accordingly, so it breaks out of the while loop as needed.

```
def func(it):
    item = next(it)
    res = item.do_many_different_things()
    yield res

it = iter(range(1, 10))

condition = True
while condition:
    for item in func(it):
        condition = item
```

This will run all elements from `1..9`, because they are all truthy. If you start this with the regular `range(10)` it would stop on the first element since it's 0.

---

Once the method return `False`, the while loop breaks.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo you're totally right; thanks. I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code, nested loops and items are, so I will just show you how to break out from nested loops spread across different functions. I will also show you, how you can differentiate three cases:
1. Your `item.do_many_different_things()` method wants to break
2. You ran out of items
3. Your `condition` evaluates to `False`

This is purely educational to show you some Python features which you might find useful, not necessarily in this exact combination.

```
from __future__ import print_function
# I'm on Python 3 - you will need the above line on Python 2

# I don't know what your code is supposed to do so I'll just generate random integers
from random import Random

r = Random()
r.seed()


class BreakOutNested(Exception): pass


class Item(object):

    def do_many_different_things(self):
        x = r.randint(0, 50)
        if x == 50:
            raise BreakOutNested()
        self.x = x


def iterator_0(item):
    for i in range(5):
        item.do_many_different_things()
        yield i

def iterator_1(items):
    for item in items:
        for i in iterator_0(item):
            item.i = i
            yield item


items = iterator_1(Item() for i in range(5))
x = 50

try:
    while x != 0:
        item = next(items)
        print(item.i, item.x)
        x = item.x
except BreakOutNested:
    print('Broke out from many loops with exception trick')
except StopIteration:
    print('Simply ran out of items')
else:
    print('Got x == 0')
```

Run this a couple of times as the exit scenario is random.